# Log what was just selected without temporary table?

Tags: sql, logging, sql-server-2000

In a stored procedure I am selecting from a table using variables passed in. Then, I want to log what is selected. Is there any way to do this without using a temporary table or table variable?

The select statement:

```
Select userId, firstName, lastName, address
from myTable
where userName = @userName and password = @password
```

Then, I want to log the userId, firstName, lastName, and address that were selected. So:

```
Insert into loginLog...[results gotten above]
```

Note: I only want to log it if there is only one result returned. If more than one result is returned, I still want to select all the results, but I do not want to log it.

Comment: Just to mention, the OUTPUT clause would be useful here... but they only added that in SQL 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your `select` to populate local variables in the stored procedure. Log the results, then `select` the variable to return them to the caller:

```
declare
  @userID    int          ,
  @firstName varchar(255) ,
  @lastName  varchar(255) ,
  @address   varchar(255)   ,
  @rows      int

select @userID = userId ,
       @firstName = firstName ,
       @lastName  = lastName  ,
       @address   = address
from myTable
where ...

set @rows = @@rowcount

insert loginLog
select @userID , @firstName , @lastName , @address
where @rows > 0

select userID = @userID ,
       firstName  = @firstName ,
       lastName   = @lastName  ,
       address    = @address
where @rows > 0
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was typing.  Well, formatting would have been different, but that's about all...

Comment: I realized I made a mistake and there could be more than one result. It's just that I only want to log it if there is more than one result. In light of this, your answer no longer works...

Comment: Then you're stuck with a temp table.You could probably wire up something with SQL trace to trap the desired table selects, but the performance hit would be unpleasant.